# Cancelling an event using jquery mouseout

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I have three business(items) where on each item I am making call to the database and getting the information on an ajax call.
Now the problem is on mouseover of a second business , the time is five minutes to complete the server side operation and the user cannot move to other business.

So, I am planning to keep the user waiting for the opeartion if and only if the mouseover is still in business 2,on mouse out of business cancel the events in it.

Is it possible to stop all the ongoing operations on mouseout event , unbind event? or any event is available to stop and release the cursor?

Comment: Show your code, so it's easier to recognize your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hope you are making ajax call through JQuery Ajax package. 
If so you can easily stop the event using below technique.

```
var a = $.ajax({YOUR_AJAX_PARAMETERS_HERE});
a.abort();
```

If everything is getting freeze on your call, try [web workers](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp) feature in html5.

If you still get any issues, please post your code snippet or plunker.